# How can I pass an array in a url to be retrieved by javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

I am trying to pass an array in a url so I tried this:

```
?question_id=10&value=1&array=["Saab","Volvo","BMW"]
```

This didn't work (didn't think it would, but it's a start).

It's a key and value array anyway so I needed something like this:

```
&array[28]=1&array[9]=1&array[2]=0&array[28]=0
```

But that didn't work either

Comment: Use `post` to pass array

Comment: Passing large arrays via GET can be troublesome as not all browsers support large GET requests. I think GET URLS are limited to 255 bytes, some browsers support larger ones, but the RFC's define it as 255.

Answer (score 2):

in jquery try this

```
var arr = [1, 4, 9];
var url = '/page.php?arr=' + JSON.stringify(arr);
window.location.href = url;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass an array, you just have to set the different parts of the array in the URI like

```
http://example.com/myFile.php?cars[]=Saab&cars[]=volvo&cars[]=BMW
```

So you get your formated array in `$_GET['cars']`

```
print_r($_GET['cars']); // array('Saab', 'Volvo', 'BMW')
```

To get such a result in javascript you can use this kind of code

```
var cars = ['Saab', 'Volvo', 'BMW'],
    result = '';

for (var i = cars.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    results += 'cars[]='+arr[i]+'&';
}

results = results.substr(0, results.length-1); // cars[]=BMW&cars[]=Volvo&cars[]=Saab
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass like this

```
?question_id=10&value=1&my_array=Saab,Volvo,BMW
```

and you can get like

```
<?php
    $my_array = explode(',',$_GET['my_array']);
?>
```

or you can try like this

```
$aValues = array('Saab','Volvo','BMW');
$url = 'http://example.com/index.php?';
$url .= 'aValues[]=' . implode('&amp;aValues[]=', array_map('urlencode', $aValues));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also try this:

```
?arr[]="Saab"&arr[]="BMW"
```

Using the jQuery getUrlParam extension I can get url variables very easily

or in PHP

```
var_dump($_GET);
```